# Positioning of Logo and hamburger menu

Tags: html, css

I am not able to position a css hamburger menu next to my logo :( I put the css hamburger and the logo both in the header. I managed to float the logo on the right but it should be at the same line as the menu.

After the header I'd like to make some boxes. BTW this will be the mobile version of the site.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header_logo {
  float: right;
}


/*
     * Made by Erik Terwan
     * 24th of November 2015
     * MIT License
     *
     *
     * If you are thinking of using this in
     * production code, beware of the browser
     * prefixes.
     */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  margin: 19px 0 5px 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
     * Just a quick hamburger
     */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #006663;
  /*spans*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/* 
     * Transform all the slices of hamburger
     * into a crossmark.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #fff;
}


/*
     * But let's hide the middle one.
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/*
     * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
     * Make this absolute positioned
     * at the top left of the screen
     */

#menu
/*Hier Position ändern! Auch Z-index*/

{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3 width: 20%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -30px;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #006663;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/*
     * And let's slide it in from the left
     */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#box_dates {
  background-color: green;
}

#box_about {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Batukeros - Space Groove Gang</title>
  <link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/responsive.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <!--menu-->
      <!--    Made by Erik Terwan    -->
      <!--   24th of November 2015   -->
      <!--        MIT License        -->
      <nav role="navigation">
        <div id="menuToggle">
          <!--
        A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
        so you can use the :checked selector on it.
        -->
          <input type="checkbox" />

          <!--
        Some spans to act as a hamburger.
        
        They are acting like a real hamburger,
        not that McDonalds stuff.
        -->
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>

          <!--
        Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
        but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
        -->
          <ul id="menu">
            <a href="#">
              <li>Home</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>About</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Info</li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
              <li>Contact</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <img class="header_logo" src="../images/logo_s.png" alt="logo batukeros">

      <!--  <h1 class="header__title">
              Space Groove Gang
            </h1> -->
    </header>


    <main>
      <section class="content">
        <section id="box_dates" class="box">Termine</section>
        <section id="box_about" class="box">Über uns</section>
        <section id="box_pics" class="box">Fotos</section>
        <section id="box_imprint" class="box">Impressum</section>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should float the navigation too, also add `display: flex;` to the `header`

Comment: Well, it seems to be a silly question as it is rated -3... but thank you Sean for answering it and for helping me! It worked :)